# typescript definitions for officejs v1.1

Tags: typescript, office-js

Is there anyway we could find the type definitions for the [office js api v.1.1](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.1/Office.context) to be used in javascript. There is one [available here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/office-js) but it seems to be for the latest version (yes 1.1 is quite different in some places as compared to the latest version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, its not that the api's are different. In some of the methods i noticed few parameters were skipped and it still worked which lead me to think the APIs might be different (in future versions).

Example, in Office.body both these seem to work.

```
getAsync(coercionType, options, callback)
getAsync(coercionType, callback)
```

Answer (score 1):

The @types/office-js version, generated off of https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/office-js/index.d.ts, is the one true source of the d.ts information.

What about it are you finding incorrect?

For the new Office 2016 wave of APIs for Excel, Word, and OneNote, the JavaScript is machine-generated, as is the d.ts -- so it should be accurate.  For the 2013 "Common" APIs and for Outlook APIs (i.e., anything under the `Office` namespace), it is hand-written, but I do remember Outlook updating that file fairly recently, and fixing some of the earlier omissions.

If there are still any, let us know, and I can redirect to the right folks.

Comment: Lets take for example getAsync method in Office.body. The method signature in 1.1 does not include options whereas the versions after that do.

Comment: I understand not many folks might be using 1.1 at this point but let me know if this is something you're planning to address..

Comment: Not sure I understood.  What are you calling 1.1, is it the shared APIs of Office 2013 SP1+?  Are you saying that in some version of Office the method only had a callback whereas a later version added options as well?  Or is it that the TS intellisense for it is simply wrong (whereas the JS vsdoc is right...)?

Comment: Hey Michael, so i might have misunderstood. getAsync seems to work even if we skip passing options. So, both getAsync(coercionType, options, callback) and getAsync(coercionType, callback) seem to work in the same way. That's the reason i thought maybe the parameters might have changed.